PostgreSQL connection in Windows Forms
I'm working on a C# .Net 3.5 application with Windows Forms. Yes, I have to use something that old, because I'm writing for a Pocket PC 2003/Windows CE 4.20.0 (Build 14053).
I have two connections to external databases, one happens via a REST API, and the other one via PostgreSQL.
I'd like to not do anything with any middleware, and instead connect to the DB directly.
I have installed the PostgreSQL ODBC driver on my system, but whenever I try to add it, Visual Studio 2008 throws the following error: "The new connection uses a data provider that is not supported.".
What's the best way forward here? I'd like to use the native tools that are already built into the toolchain, if possible.

I found a solution: Manually import ngpsql as a package.
Here's how:
Find the latest version of npsql on NuGet that supports my FrameworkVersion (in this case 2.2.7, as I'm building against .net 3.5), and download the .nupkg file from NuGet. Extract it as a .zip, copy \lib\net35 to your project folder. Right-click on on references, add reference to npsql.dll in the Browse tab.
